# Bind DataGrid to a Matrix

Tags: wpf, matrix, wpfdatagrid

I have a 'matrix' object like follows:

```
public class Matrix
{    
   public Dictionary<string, string> PropertyBags { ... }
   // Sample Property Bag: [{"Column A", "A"}, {"Column B", "B"}]

   public List<PropertyBags Row { ... }    
}
```

I wonder what's a practical solution for displaying my objects in WPF DataGrid?

Thanks.

Comment: See http://www.paulstovell.com/dynamic-datagrid

Comment: @sll - sounds good to me, would you put it as an answer?

Comment: ok I'll put this as an answer with some comments from me as I've done such a dynamic grid recently

Comment: the idea is pretty simple, I was just hoping on existance of a trick with property descriptors or something of that nature, cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, you can do it in code behind of a Grid View. The idea is to bind a custom data set to a `grid.DataSource` property and then add columns dynamically, see examples by links below.
Also the second link provides an good example using Dependency Property which bound to a `ItemsSource` of a grid in XAML, also DP has `OnPropertyChangedCallback` provided so each time you update a data set by new value:

- PropertyChanged get raised which automaticalli trigger an callback
- In callback you are populating grid.DataSource by a new data items
- UI get updated because in XAML grid has

Links to the examples:

- [WPF Dynamically Generated DataGrid](http://www.paulstovell.com/dynamic-datagrid)
- [Binding a ListView to a Data Matrix](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPF_DynamicListView.aspx)